# jQuery cannot load plugin file using ajax before calling the plugin function, thus, gives kind of weird result

Tags: jquery, ajax, runtime-error, eventtrigger

I am trying to load jsvascript files at runtime like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var SRC_URL = 'http://localhost/mytest/scripts/';
var scripts = [
    'jquery/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js',
    'app/mbro.js'
];

for (var x = 0; x < scripts.length; x++) {
    sUrl = SRC_URL + scripts[x];
    $.ajax({
        url: sUrl,
        dataType: "script",
        async: false,
        success: function() {
            console.log(x + ': ' + sUrl);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

What I am trying here is to load `jquery.colorbox.js` before loading `mbro.js`, 
`mbro.js` just tries to initialize colorbox on click of a link.
The content of the `mbro.js` is as follows

```
(function ($, W, D) {
    var abc = {};
    abc.UTIL = {
        openPopup: function () {
            $(".mbro").colorbox({
                inline: false,
            });
        },
    };

    $(D).ready(function ($) {
        abc.UTIL.openPopup();
    });

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

The HTML looks like this

```
<a class="mbro" href="media/popup">Browse</a>
```

But I am getting this error

```
TypeError: $(...).colorbox is not a function
$(".mbro").colorbox({
```

What should be cause of this error and how to resolve this situation. Please give me some suggestions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I still didn't caught your error, check that your script path for colorbox plugin is rigth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$.getScript()` jQuery method and keep async behaviour of ajax requests, e.g:

```
(function loadScript(x) {
    sUrl = SRC_URL + scripts[x];
    $.getScript(sUrl, function(){
        if(scripts[++x]) loadScript(x);
    });
}(0));
```

To keep cache behaviour, you should use `$.ajax` method as mentionned in comment below. 
Here a workaround if for some reason you want to still use `$.getScript` method:

> By default, $.getScript() sets the cache setting to false. This
>   appends a timestamped query parameter to the request URL to ensure
>   that the browser downloads the script each time it is requested. You
>   can override this feature by setting the cache property globally using
>   $.ajaxSetup()

```
var cacheSetting = $.ajaxSetup()['cache'];
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: true
});
(function loadScript(x) {
    sUrl = SRC_URL + scripts[x];
    $.getScript(sUrl, function () {
        if (scripts[++x]) loadScript(x);
        else {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                cache: cacheSetting 
            });     
        }       
    });
}(0));
```

Comment: Thanks for this beautiful code snippet, It just worked for me. 
If I want to cache few of the JS files over repeated page loading, is that possible to update this function?

Comment: @SamikChattopadhyay this method set cache false specifically as mentiond in DOC. I will post a workaround or you could just instead use `$.ajax` method with `dataType: "script"` and `cache: true` as options

Comment: This way it will be very easy to segregate scripts that should be cached and those don't in separate arrays and loading them separately with different ajax setup. 

But as everybody is saying, here I should use `$.ajax` with `dataType: "script"`, unfortunately my issue started from there as I described in the question above and I was using the same before I got the idea of `$.getScript`

Answer (score 0):

Sending the load request before doesn't guarantee that it will be loaded before. The best to do in your situation seems to be loading `mbro.js` inside the `success` callback of the `colorbox.js` loading. This way, you guarantee that your script is loaded only after `colorbox.js`'s loading is complete.

```
$.ajax({
    url: SRC_URL + 'jquery/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js',
    dataType: "script",
    success: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: SRC_URL + 'app/mbro.js',
            dataType: "script",
            async: false,
            success: function() {
                console.log('Done! Both loaded in the desired order!')
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**

I hadn't noticed the use of `async: false` here. Nevertheless, it's strongly non recommended to use it and it's been deprecated in the latest versions of jQuery.

Comment: Is there any way to delay the initialization of colorbox until the plugin function colorbox() gets defined after script loads.

Comment: @SamikChattopadhyay there should be no need for it. Didn't my answer work for you?

Comment: I have a circumstance where the mbro.js file require colorbox.js, validate.js, form.js might be in future some more plugins, so how I shall make certain all the plugins gets loaded before using them inside mbro.js? Your solution just confirms colorbox() is ready for initialize, but what about the other dependencies?

Comment: @SamikChattopadhyay You could use requirejs for more complex behaviour: http://requirejs.org/