# Can I cache contents loaded by jQuery.getScript()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file, loading

As per jQuery documentation (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) use more flexible `$.ajax()` method, but it doesn't work for me described in here ([jQuery cannot load plugin file using ajax before calling the plugin function, thus, gives kind of weird result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627162/jquery-cannot-load-plugin-file-using-ajax-before-calling-the-plugin-function-th))

> By default, `$.getScript()` sets the cache setting to false. This
>   appends a timestamped query parameter to the request URL to ensure
>   that the browser downloads the script each time it is requested. You
>   can override this feature by setting the cache property globally using
>   `$.ajaxSetup()`:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: true
});
```

But I need to cache few of the contents not all.

> Alternatively, you could define a new method that uses the more
>   flexible `$.ajax()` method.

It didn't work for me as it doesn't guarantee loading files in a sequence.

Now what is the best solution for this situation?

Comment: getScript gets a script file, you cannot cache part of it and not the other part

Comment: I need to cache few of the script files loaded by getScript function. I am not trying to cache a file partly. e.g. If I load 4 scripts may be 2 of them need to be cached.

Comment: *"It didn't work for me as it doesn't guarantee loading files in a sequence."* that makes no sense. `$.getScript` is using `$.ajax` internally. if `$.ajax` won't work for you, neither will `$.getScript`. (hint: $.getScript does not guarantee load order either.)

Comment: Maybe he is using `success` to guarantee load order. Something like `$.getScript('first.js').success(function(){$.getScript('second.js')})`
Having said that `$.ajax` has `success` as well so I don't know why it would matter.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.getScript({
    url: "foo.js",
    cache: true
})
```

Supported on jQuery 1.12.0 or later

Answer (score 1):

use `$.ajax` with `dataType: 'script'` and `cache: true`.

```
$.ajax({
    cache: true,
    url: 'foo.js',
    dataType: 'script', // optional, can omit if your server returns proper contentType for js files.
    success: function () {
        console.log('Hello World!');
    }
});
```

This assumes your server is responding with the headers required for the browser to cache the file.